# jquery submit event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

hello I try to grab the submit event, and then I try to pop an alert that says "werks" so I know it works. Note that I have double-checked that the jquery.js file is present in the same folder, and it is the newest jquery.min.js from the jquery website.

When I submit the form, it automatically goes into "get" mode and displays this URL in the URL bar in my browser: "`http://localhost/test.html?input=`" instead of showing me the alert.
I think jquery is trolling me. Full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('werks');
            });</script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <form id="form">
                <input type="text" name="input">
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: enclose your code in $(function(){ ... jquery code ... });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#form')` selector returns nothing, since the markup form isn't loaded yet. Move script block after form, or wrap it in `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form id="form">
                <input type="text" name="input">
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#form').submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('werks');
            });
       });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in a document ready statement:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

       //Code Here

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('werks');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

fire your js code on document ready like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('werks');
    });
});
```